# Buddypress blank friends requests

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm having trouble with the friend requests when someone adds a friend, appears in the notification bar, but when I go to accept or reject, do not show any friend request.

I did a debug and queries are failing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM u.user_id the wp_bp_xprofile_data u WHERE id = AND u.field_id u.user_id IN (2) ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 0 u.value, 20 

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT u.user_id) FROM WHERE u.field_id wp_bp_xprofile_data u = AND u.user_id IN (2)
```

It's not filling the u.field_id, I do not know what to do, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, in WP_OPTIONS the option_value in option_name bp-xprofile-fullname-field-name was wrong, doing an update in the database worked.

Thanks.